# Getting 401 Unauthorized from Google API Resumable Update

Tags: google-docs-api

I am trying to integrate upload of arbitrary files to Google Docs into an existing application. This used to work before using resumable upload became mandatory. I am using Java client libraries.

The application is doing the upload in 2 steps:
- get the resourceId of the file
- upload the data

To get the resourceId I am uploading a 0-size file (i.e. Content-Length=0). I am passing ?convert=false in the resumable URL (i.e. https://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full?convert=false).

I am passing "application/octet-stream" as content-type. This seems to work, though I do get different resourcesIds -  "file:..." resourceIds for things like images, but "pdf:...." resourceIds for PDFs.

The second step constructs a URL based on the resourceId obtained previously and performs a search (getEntry). The URL is in the form of https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/file%3A.....

Once the entry is found the ResumableGDataFileUploader is used to update the content (0-byte file) with the actual data from the file being uploaded. This operation fails with 401 Unauthorized response when building ResumableGDataFileUploader instance.

I've tried with ?convert=false as well as ?new-revision=true and both of these at the same time. The result is the same.

The relevant piece of code:

```
MediaFileSource mediaFile = new MediaFileSource(
    tempFile, "application/octet-stream");

final ResumableGDataFileUploader.Builder builder = 
    new ResumableGDataFileUploader.Builder(client, mediaFile, documentListEntry);
builder.executor(MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor());
builder.requestType(ResumableGDataFileUploader.RequestType.UPDATE);

// This is where it fails
final ResumableGDataFileUploader resumableGDataFileUploader = builder.build();
resumableGDataFileUploader.start();

return tempFile.length();
```

The "client" is an instance of DocsService, configured to use OAuth. It is used to find "documentListEntry" immediately before the given piece of code.

I had to explicitly specify request type, since it seems the client library code contains a bug causing NullPointerException for "update existing entry" case.

I have a suspicion that the issue is specifically in the sequence of actions (upload 0-byte file to get the resourceId, then update with actual file) but I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

Please help?

Answer (score 3):

This code snippet works for me using OAuth 1.0 and OAuth 2.0:

```
static void uploadDocument(DocsService client) throws IOException, ServiceException,
    InterruptedException {
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

  File file = new File("<PATH/TO/FILE>");
  String mimeType = DocumentListEntry.MediaType.fromFileName(file.getName()).getMimeType();

  DocumentListEntry documentEntry = new DocumentListEntry();
  documentEntry.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("<DOCUMENT TITLE>"));

  int DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE = 2 * 512 * 1024;
  ResumableGDataFileUploader.Builder builder =
      new ResumableGDataFileUploader.Builder(
          client,
          new URL(
              "https://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full?convert=false"),
          new MediaFileSource(file, mimeType), documentEntry).title(file.getName())
          .requestType(RequestType.INSERT).chunkSize(DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE).executor(executor);

  ResumableGDataFileUploader uploader = builder.build();
  Future<ResponseMessage> msg = uploader.start();
  while (!uploader.isDone()) {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
      throw ie; // rethrow
    }
  }

  DocumentListEntry uploadedEntry = uploader.getResponse(DocumentListEntry.class);
  // Print the document's ID.
  System.out.println(uploadedEntry.getId());
  System.out.println("Upload is done!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't answer my question. Yes, uploading "in one go" works. I am not able to use this at the moment. I need to create an entry to obtain document id, then in another place later in the code, search for this entry by id and upload the actual content. The "first step" of the process I've tried to describe in the original question is virtually identical to the code you've presented, but I am having the problem with the "second step" - updating an entry with content.

Comment: For updates, you can use the DocumentListEntry retrieved from the API instead of instantiating a new one and use RequestType.UPDATE as the request type.

Comment: Hmm, have you looked an read the original question and reviewed the code snippet? I am retrieving the entry from the API and I am using UPDATE as the request type. It fails with "UNAUTHORIZED" response.

Comment: I tried this code with OAuth 2.0 to update a file's content and it worked perfectly. I then changed the authorization mechanism to OAuth 1.0 and indeed got an Unauthorized response. I'll investigate the issue, in the meantime, can you switch to OAuth 2.0?

Comment: I found out where the issue is coming from. If you are running the client library from the source code, remove this [line](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/src/com/google/gdata/client/media/MediaService.java?spec=svn505&r=189#689); the repository will be updated shortly. Again, migrating to OAuth 2.0 would be a better solution.

Comment: Thank you this helped. I am not at liberty to migrate at the moment but will pass the message to people responsible.

Comment: This should be resolved in version [1.47.1](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/downloads/detail?name=gdata-src.java-1.47.1.zip).