# Faild to upload a image file into Google Doc with google format via java api

Tags: java, google-docs, google-docs-api

I need upload a image into Google doc with google format in order to retrieving it back and saving the storage uasage as well. Below it my code sample, it was work fine but broken recently, What I got just a empty document. Could anyone help me?

```
DocsService client = new DocsService("testappv1"); 
client.setUserCredentials(username, password); 
client.setProtocolVersion(DocsService.Versions.V2); 
File file = new File("C:/test.jpg"); 
DocumentEntry newDocument = new DocumentEntry(); 
newDocument.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("test")); 
String mimeType = DocumentListEntry.MediaType.fromFileName(file.getName()).getMimeType();
newDocument.setMediaSource(new MediaFileSource(file, mimeType)); 
newDocument = client.insert(destFolderUrl, newDocument);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10195674/1106381). Also, remove this line from your code:

```
client.setProtocolVersion(DocsService.Versions.V2);
```

You should use the default version (3.0) whenever possible.

Comment: Hi Alain, I had tried your code, it did work. But my problem is I do want to upload a image file with google format in order to saving storage uasge. If I remove "convert=false" then I still get a empty document.

Comment: In this case, you will need to upload an HTML file including an img tag. The image can be linked to a public URL but if that doesn't work, include the image as a base64 encoded blob.

Comment: Hi Alian, seems base64 encoded blob does not work properly. my code is below. I use `Base64.encode(out.toByteArray())` convert image file into base64 string, then compose a html file (I have written this file to local disk, it can be opened in browser with image). But when I upload this html sting onto google doc I still get an empty document, even I directly drag the html file that I generated into google doc I still get an empty document as well.

Comment: By the way public URL is working, but in my case the image file in my local disk. Any idea of this?